# Why were parentheses chosen for function calls in most languages?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages, parentheses

Whilst dreaming up a new programming language (keyword: dreaming), I wondered why parentheses were chosen for function calls. For example, in most programming languages, a function call would look like this:

```
print("Hello, world!");
```

Was this decision based on algebraic functions from the time before programming was around? Perhaps the question could be asked in a different way if this were true. In my opinion, brackets are easier to type. They are typically closer or just as close as the parentheses keys; plus, they don't require a shift key. Why were brackets placed in an arguably easier location on the keyboard than parentheses? Programming or not, parentheses are used much more than brackets (unless you are a hardcore Objective-C programmer).

**EDIT:** This is very related for the second half of my question but still doesn't cover the first part: [Why is it harder to type parentheses () than square brackets [] on a standard keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/358218/why-is-is-harder-to-type-parentheses-than-square-brackets-on-a-standard-ke)

**EDIT 2:** I'm not too sure how this isn't constructive. It does not fit the description under the not constructive vote-to-close option.

Comment: I guess, it comes from `math`.

Comment: Check haskell or scala, parentheses are optional... btw: on German keyboards parentheses are easier to type (shift + 8 | 9), brackets are (AltGr + 8 | 9), whereas AltGr is right to the spacebar :-)

Answer (score 1):

Curves can be written in a single motion, making them easier to write.

Even if square brackets had originally been used by classical mathematicians, writing quickly would transform these into more rounded characters. From then the style was transferred to programming languages. I would imagine the same theory answers why parentheses are the dominant bracket in English.

Answer (score 0):

Languages were initially created to help us make computers do what their name implied: compute.  The various brackets ('parenthesis' is more of an American term) used today all existed in mathmatics originally.  We had curly brackets for sets, square brackets for quantities and closed intervals, parenthesis for lists, open intervals, coordinates, etc.  It makes logical sense that the goal was to be able to naturally express our existing formulas.  That likely played a direct role in the modern usage much like newer languages borrow concepts from the languages before them.  It's not just the symbols, it's also many of the words we use in computer science today.

I would disagree with the argument that key layout and finger proximity should've played a role in changing which symbols were used at that time.  As [a look back at the history of keyboards](http://www.daskeyboard.com/blog/?page_id=1329) will show us, there have been many different layouts.  Computers like the Apple II didn't even have dedicated square bracket keys whatsoever.  Plus, as we all know, the dominate layout these days (QWERTY) was made that way with more focus on preventing type bar jamming than easy typing.

Just be happy you don't use Dvorak.  Those square brackets are right next to the parenthesis.  ;)

Comment: QWERTY did prevent bar jamming, but it also made typing easier using the same idea that you shouldn't use characters close to each other in quick succession.